# App Crashes On Device But Not In Simulator

Tags: ios5, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have an application that calls out to a web service. It runs fine in the emulator but crashes on the device. When I debug the crash happens when accessing the web service for the first time. The following is the info that I get:

Mar  7 15:58:52 Justins-iPhone SpringBoard[15] : My App failed to launch in time

Mar  7 15:58:52 Justins-iPhone SpringBoard[15] : Forcing crash report of MyApp[112]...

Mar  7 15:58:52 Justins-iPhone SpringBoard[15] : Finished crash reporting.

Mar  7 15:58:52 Justins-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:My App[0xc356][112]) : (UIKitApplication:My App[0xc356]) Exited: Killed: 9

Mar  7 15:58:52 Justins-iPhone SpringBoard[15] : Application 'My App' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Mar  7 15:58:52 Justins-iPhone ReportCrash[113] : Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2012-03-07-155852_Justins-iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a call to this service in FinishedLaunching in the AppDelegate and it takes longer than ~17 seconds the device will kill your application.

Generally speaking any IO bound tasks such as web services should be offloaded to a background thread:

```
_client = new ServiceClient();
_client.DoSomethingCompleted += Handle_DoSomethingCompleted;
_client.DoSomethingAsync();
```

Those same restrictions may or may not be enforced in simulator.

Comment: It seems that recent versions of iOS simulator does not enforce this anymore (pretty sure it was the case in earlier 4.x releases but can't recall when it changed).

Answer (score 1):

Don't do blocking tasks in the main thread, use async or a new thread. The problem is you're polling a webservice before the first view is rendered. This causes your app start to time out and ios will kill your process.

`Mar 7 15:58:52 Justins-iPhone SpringBoard[15] : My App failed to launch in time`